# SQL Server Max Memory

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-server, sql

In our farm, we have 3 servers dedicated for SQL Server and all three are consuming 99% of the memory available. Looking in to it I learned that we didn't change the Max Memory setting in our SQL Server and therefore its consuming everything available.

This is giving us issues because its conflicting with our backup tool.

Our farm has a size of 2.5TB divided in the three servers(1TB, 1,3TB, 0.2TB). How can I measure the impact of setting a max memory now, changing the amount available for SQL from 64GB to 58GB?

Is there a Microsoft Guideline/Best Practice on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is best practice that limit the memory utilization for SQL server, as SQL server eat all the available memory. SQL server is good in sharing the memory with resources if they need but still best practice is cap the SQL server ram utilization so that we will enough for OS and other program running on the server.

You can change the max memory on the server anytime, this setting does not required SQL instance restart. Once you change your configuration you can monitor you server's performance.

[Optimizing SQL Server for SharePoint 2010](http://mscerts.wmlcloud.com/sharepoint/optimizing%20sql%20server%20for%20sharepoint%202010%20(part%201).aspx)

[Server Memory Server Configuration Options](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178067(v=sql.110).aspx)

Comment: Per Microsoft`s recommendation a DB bigger than 2TB should have 64GBs of RAM. How does this works in my case? Should I consider each dedicated server or the sum of everything?

Comment: we have more than 2 TB on SQL server and running with 64gb( 60 for SQL+4 OS), we had no issue. But it depends usage of the SharePoint nad may be different for your farm. where u are reading that recommendation?

Comment: Here: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc298801(v=office.14).aspx

Comment: yes it is saying for 32 gb for 2TB  and 64GB from 2Tb to 5TB. So you are good